# Problem in microphone circuit

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, audio, microphone

[image]

I've placed the circuit on the breadboard and found an unexpected low-frequency noise appearing again and again. The computer microphone doesn't show this type of distortion. But my circuit is showing. Can anyone explain to me why is this happening?

[image]

I played a youtube track to test the microphone performance, but that noise distorted it (photo was taken at 390 Hz).

[image]

[image]

**How do I solve this problem?**

Comment: Remove the microphone i.e. just disconnect it - now what do you see?

Comment: Why are you using an LM386 power amplifier here as a microphone pre-amp?

Comment: @brhans I found this in a google search. And the datasheet says it has 20 - 200x gain. But I checked using the TLC2272 Op-amp. There was no output at 20x gain. I'll check tomorrow using 100x gain.

Comment: @Andyaka It's 12.45 am here. I've packed the oscilloscope. I'll attach the waveshape in the morning.

Comment: @SadatRafi don't try the LM386 with more amplification – this circuit is bad by design. Wherever you found a circuit that uses a power amplifier as microphone, that's a terrible idea. also , why would you ask a question an hour befor going to bed – now nobody can ask you any questions for clarification!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll check with rail to rail op-amp.

Comment: I've checked with LM358. There is no noise and the circuit works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be picking up environmental noise; basically all aspects of your implementation make that likely:

1. Breadboard is exceptionally great at coupling in signals you don't want
2. So are long, loops of wire
3. You're using an amplifier IC with known-to-be-bad output noise, without appropriate filtering
4. Your schematic has no decoupling capacitor on VCC of the amplifier

additionally,

5. you're using an audio *power* amp as a preamplifier - that's a bad choice, and might/will lead to distortion. An opamp circuite (eg. the simple inverting or non-inverting amplifier) with appropriate dampening of high frequencies (e.g. through a capacitor in the negative feedback path) would be a better choice, and on top of that, use much less power. Even used as a small power amplfier, the LM386 is really the worst commercially available audio amplifier.